# Can GPU be used to run programs that run on CPU?

Tags: gpu

Can Gpu be used to run programs that run on Cpu like getting input from keyboard and mouse or playing music or reading the contents of a text file using Direct3D and OpenGL Api?

Comment: Short: No. Long: You'd be mad to try. On the other hand, if you have a few trillion floating point operations to perform, the GPU will be on your side. Google for OpenCL or CUDA.

Comment: the company Graphcore designs chips to have many cores which execute CPU code ... so no its not a GPU however its a direct competitor to GPU vendors as its catering to machine learning training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPU has no direct access on any memory that is mapped by the OS to be accessed within client code (i.e. code, which is executed in user-mode while the instructions are executed on the CPU).
In addition the GPU is not supposed to perform stuff like this, it aims to perform floating point arithmetic at a high speed. And finally you would never use Direct3D or OpenGL to perform anything that is not related to graphics, except you are only going to use the compute shader.
General purpose computations are performed with OpenCL or CUDA on the GPU, such as image manipulation or physics simulations.
You can, however, gather any data on the CPU, send it to the GPU for further processing and finally write it back again into memory accessible from the CPU.

Comment: Not necessarily true; What if you want to delegate floating point operations from CPU to the GPU and get the result; is there never a case when  this is more efficient than using CPU? I understand there is upload and download cost but is there a way to do this for the sake of proof of concept? Possibly by sending the buffer as a texture, and then perform complicated shader and then get the result in an output buffer. If I understand correctly; GPUs have native support for matrix operations, which might net performance boost for some problems.